# Polymorphic reasoning

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell and in internet I've found is [paper](https://people.mpi-sws.org/~dreyer/tor/papers/wadler.pdf) from Philip Wadler.
I read it and did not understand at all, but it somehow connects to polymorphic function.

For example:

```
polyfunc :: a -> a -> a
```

It is a polymorphic function of any type.

What is the free theorem in connection of the example `polyfunc`?

Comment: What do you mean by it's a polymorphic function "of any type?" That's not how I'd describe it and, just in case, we should make sure there isn't a grammatical misunderstanding first.

Comment: What does Philip Wadler want to say? What does it mean free theorem in connection with polymorphic type?

Comment: As an aside, this isn't actually an important topic for learning Haskell. Don't let it stop you from doing the most important thing - writing code.

Comment: https://youtu.be/DSyZ6jnMJYg "Why Wadler's paper is hard to understand"

Answer (score 8):

I feel like if I actually understood that paper then any code I wrote would be coauthored by God.

My best guess for this problem though is that all `polyfunc` can do is either always return the first argument or always return the second argument. So there are actually only two implementations of `polyfunc`,

```
polyfuncA a _ = a
polyfuncB _ b = b
```

The paper gives you a way to prove that claim.

This is a very important concept. For example, I've been involved in data quality research previously. This free theorem says that there is no function which can select the best data from two arbitrary pieces of data. We have to know something more. Its actually a no-brainer that I was surprised to find some people willing to overlook.

Answer (score 3):

I've never really understood the algorithm laid out in that paper either, so I thought I would try to figure it out.

```
(1) Type of function in question
f :: a -> a -> a

(2) Rephrasing as a relation
f : ∀X. X -> X -> X

(3) By parametricity
(f, f) ∈ ∀X. X -> X -> X

(4) By definition of ∀ on relations
for all Q : A <=> A',
  (fA, fA') ∈ Q -> Q -> Q

(5) Applying definition of -> on relations to the first -> in (4)
for all Q : A <=> A',
  for all (x, x') ∈ Q,
    (fA x, fA' x') ∈ Q -> Q

(6) Applying definition of -> on relations to (5)
for all Q : A <=> A',
  for all (x, x') ∈ Q,
    for all (y, y') ∈ Q,
      (fA x y, fA' x' y') ∈ Q
```

At this point I was done expanding the relational definition, but wasn't sure how to get this back from relations into terms of functions and types, so I went and found a webapp that will [automatically derive the free theorem for a type](http://www-ps.iai.uni-bonn.de/cgi-bin/free-theorems-webui.cgi). I won't spoil (yet) what result it gives, but looking at it did help me figure out the next step in my proof.

The next step is to get back into function-land from relation-land, by noting that Q can be the type of any function at all and this will still hold.

```
(7) Specializing Q to a function g :: p -> q
for all p, q
  for all g :: p -> q
    where g x = x'
      and g y = y'
        g (f x y) = f x' y'

(8) By definitions of x' and y'
for all p, q
  for all g :: p -> q
    g (f x y) = f (g x) (g y)
```

That looks true, right? It is equivalent to use `g` to transform both elements and then let `f` choose between them, or to let `f` choose an element and then transform it with `g`. By parametricity, `f` can't change whether it chooses the left or right element based on anything that `g` does.

Of course the claim given in trevor cook's answer is true: `f` must either always choose its first argument, or always choose its second. I'm not sure whether the free theorem I derived is equivalent to that, or is a weaker version of it.

---

And incidentally, this is a special case of something that is already covered explicitly in the paper. It gives the theorem for

```
k :: x -> y -> x
```

which of course is the same as your function `f`, where `x ~ a` and `y ~ a`. The result that it gives is the same as the one I described:

```
for all a, b, x, y
  a (k x y) = k (a x) (b y)
```

if we choose `b=a` to make the two results equivalent.

Comment: It's funny. I have no idea how that algorithm works, but I have seen its output enough to immediately know what it would give for that input.

Answer (score 0):

Wadler's "Theorems for free" (TFF) paper is not a good reference for learning about relational parametricity. The TFF paper is focused on abstract theory but, if you need a practical algorithm, the paper does not actually give it to you. The explanations in TFF have a number of important omissions that will confuse anyone who does not already know a great deal about relational parametricity.

The first thing TFF does not explain is that a function will satisfy a "free theorem" only if the code of the function is fully parametric (restricted in a number of ways).

"Fully parametric" code is a function with type parameters, whose arguments are typed using only those type parameters, and whose code is purely functional and does not try to examine at run time what types are assigned to the type parameters. The code must treat all types as totally unknown, arbitrary type parameters. The code must work with all types in the same way.

With these restrictions, the code will satisfy a certain law, in most cases this will be the "naturality" law, but in some cases the law will be more complicated. The paper "Theorems for free" shows many examples of such laws but does not explain a general algorithm for deriving those theorems.

To prove that those laws always hold, one uses the technique of relational parametricity. This is a complicated and powerful technique where one replaces functions (viewed as many-to-one binary relations) by arbitrary (many-to-many) binary relations and then reformulates the naturality law in terms of relations. The result is a "relational naturality law". At the end, one replaces relations again by functions and tries to derive an equation.

I recently recorded a tutorial about relational parametricity, with code examples in Scala. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jf2VFB90Q0s&list=PLcoadSpY7rHUO0I1zdcbu9EeByYbwPSQ6

My tutorial does not follow Wadler's TFF paper but instead explains a simple and straightforward approach focused on practical results: how to derive the free theorem and reason about relations effectively. In this approach, it becomes easier to derive the "free theorem" for a given type and also to prove the "parametricity theorem": fully parametric functions will always satisfy one "free theorem" per type parameter.

Of course, for practical usage you don't necessarily need to go through the proof of the parametricity theorem, but you do need to be able to write the free theorem itself.

The key element of my tutorial is the idea of "lifting a relation to a type constructor". If you have a relation `r: A <=> B` and a type constructor `F A` then you can lift `r` to a relation of type `F A <=> F B`.

This lifting operation is denoted by `rmap_F`. The relation `rmap_F r` has type `F A <=> F B`.

The lifting operation `rmap_F` is defined by induction on the type structure of `F`. The details of that definition are somewhat technical (and are not adequately explained in the TFF paper!). The most important step in learning about relational parametricity is to understand the practical technique for lifting relations to type constructors. This is explained in my tutorial, and it's too long to write it here. The definition explains how to to lift `r` to a trivial type constructor `F A = C` where `C` is a fixed type, to `F A = A`, to `F A = Either (G A) (H A)`, to `F A = (G A, H A)`, to `F A = G A -> H A`, etc.

The definition of `rmap` is analogous to the functor lifting `fmap` that lifts a function of type `A -> B` to a function of type `F A -> F B`. However, the functor lifting works only for covariant `F`, while the relational lifting works for any `F`, even if it is neither covariant nor contravariant, such as `F A = A -> A -> A`. This is the crucial feature that shows why relational technique is useful at all.

Let us apply the relational technique to the type `forall A. A -> A -> A`.
We define `F A = A -> A -> A`. We take an arbitrary fully parametric function `t` of type `forall A. F A`. The relational naturality law says: for any relation `r: A <=> B` between any types `A` and `B` the function `t` must be in the relation `(t, t) ∈ rmap_F r`.

Now we need to do two things: 1) select `r` to be the graph relation of some function `f: A -> B`, denoted `r = graph f`, and 2) use the definition of `rmap_F` to compute `rmap_F (graph f)` explicitly.

The definition of `rmap_F` gives:

```
 (t1, t2) ∈ rmap_F r    ===   
    for all a1: A, a2: A, b1: B, b2: B, 
    if (a1, b1) ∈ r and (a2, b2) ∈ r
    then (t a1 a2, t b1 b2) ∈ r
```

Translating this with r = graph f, we get:

```
 (a1, b1) ∈ r    ===   b1 = f a1
 (a2, b2) ∈ r    ===   b2 = f a2
 (t a1 a2, t b1 b2) ∈ r    ===      t b1 b2 = f (t a1 a2)
```

So, we obtain the following law:

```
 for all a1: A, a2: A,
 t (f a1) (f a2) = f (t a1 a2)
```

This is actually a naturality law. This is the "free theorem" satisfied by `t`.